# How to get the list of uploaded applications by a developer in his play store account?

Tags: android, google-play

Is there any API provided by the Google or any other way to get the list of uploaded applications by a developer in his play store account ?

Ex: Lets say I want to list my all uploaded applications in the play store account.

Comment: there is not any api provide by google to getting all the apps list from the particular account

Answer (score 2):

**Well the simple answer is there is no API to do this thing.**

since these are your apps you can simply hard-code the icons into a RecyclerView or ListView along with a link leading to Google Play. This really doesn't require a third-party library as it can easily be done by yourself.

If you want this list dynamic you can use webservices from where you get the names of different apps, icons and descriptions.

Another way is you can move user to your playstore page with following line

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id={Your-Google-Account-Name}
```

This link will be opened either in the browser or in the Google Play app, whichever your user prefers, and it'll show him/her the list of all your apps.

Comment: Thanks, I think I might have to use paid APIs for this.

Comment: Hi there, do you know if there is any way of doing this by api today? I couldn't find any API to do it. Thanks

Comment: Well I am not sure about API but there are multiple ways to do that now a days. You can use Github Actions, bitrise, fastlane, there are many other tool like this

Comment: @Ravi is google has stopped this because from last few days this is not working.